# how to remove certain values from a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What happens is that I have this set of data and in the column named `Fecha de diagnóstico` there are many terms like `00:00:00` that I want to eliminate, do you know any method with which I can eliminate all those terms?

Don't worry, don't pay attention to the rest, it's in Spanish.

I tried this

```
ruta.drop(ruta.loc[ruta['Fecha de diagnóstico']=='00:00:00'].index, inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't seem to work

this is i have

```
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ruta = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/datos punto 6/Casos_positivos_de_Covid-19_en_el_departamento_de_Antioquia.csv')
cambio = ruta.drop(['fecha reporte web','Fecha de notificación','Código DIVIPOLA departamento','Nombre departamento','Código DIVIPOLA municipio','Unidad de medida de edad','Código ISO del país','Nombre del país','Recuperado','Fecha de inicio de síntomas','Fecha de muerte','Fecha de recuperación','Tipo de recuperación','Pertenencia étnica','Nombre del grupo étnico','Ubicación del caso','Estado','Tipo de contagio'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Is `'Fecha de diagnóstico'` a column of date-times? Can you provide a sample dataframe?

Comment: yes, is a column of date-times

Comment: I suppose there could be a reason for just wanting the strings. Undeleted my answer.

Comment: By the way, you can select which columns to read in with `read_csv`. That way you don't have to bother with dropping them after the data is in memory. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for details on how to use the `usecols` parameter.

Comment: OP, if your question has been answered, please mark one as accepted. That way your question will be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have datetime type, keep only the date while keeping the type using:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].dt.date
```

Comment: This will return a `datetime.date`, so @samglass if you want it a string you might need to do `df['col'] = df['col'].dt.date.astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the type, and simply want the date as a string, you can format the datetimes using `.dt.strftime()`:

```py
ruta['Fecha de diagnóstico'].dt.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
```

The benefit here is that you can change the format of your date to however you want (i.e., `/` delimiters, or different order of day, month, and year).

The tradeoff is that you lose the `datetime` type, which you may want for some type of processing. If you want to preserve the `datetime` type of that column, use Mozway's answer.